# xampp mysql server is not working, shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
12:20:53 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
12:20:53 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
12:20:56 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
12:20:56 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:20:57 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

my xampp my sql server is not running. IT starts and shut down automatically. What should I do now?

Comment: First message indicates Apache is already running.  Check with Windows Task Manager to verify running.  Shutdown first for orderly shutdown, verify Service not running with Windows Task Manager, then try to start xampp.   And post last 400 lines of your error log, please.

Comment: @tariqui anik  Still not running?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have to reinstall xampp for that problem. didn't get any solution.

Comment: We will likely need to use Skype Screen Share to view what you have going on, causing your troubles.

Comment: already uninstalled that version. then I re-install xampp. it working now.